Bindinglist bound to datagridview throws error System.InvalidOperationException
I'm using C#, Winforms on .NET 4.7.2, and my project has a dataGridView bound to a BindingList<Frame>.
When I add dynamically the first object to the list, it throws System.InvalidOperationException with no more explanations why.
internal class Frame : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string pgn; 
    private string b0;
    private string b1;

    public string PGN
    {
        get => pgn;
        set { pgn = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [DisplayName("Byte 0")]
    public string B0
    {
        get => b0;
        set { b0 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [DisplayName("Byte 1")]
    public string B1
    {
        get => b1;
        set { b1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public partial class fmVisualizer : Form
{
    BindingList<Frame> Frames;

    public fmVisualizer ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Frames = new BindingList<Frame>();

        formPrincipal.FrameReceived += FrameReceived; //some event will add new data

        dgv.DataSource = Frames; //my dataGridView 

    }

    private void FrameReceived(string somePgn) 
    {       
        Frame found = Frames.Where(x => x.PGN == somePgn).FirstOrDefault();

        if (found != null)
        {
           //...
        }
        else
        {
            Frame newFrame = new Frame()
            {
                PGN = somePgn,
                B0 = "something1...",
                B1 = "something2..."
            };

            // this line throws "System.InvalidOperationException"
            Frames.Add(newFrame); 
        }
    }
}

I don't understand what may be happening. One weird thing I observed was that when it throws the error, my list, which should have zero elements since it was disabled to add the first data, it actually has one element with all fields and properties set to null.
Other thing was that if I erase the line
dgv.DataSource = Frames;

it works fine, my first element is added, and there's no null element inside the list.

Does the FrameReceived run in the UI thread or a worker thread? If it's non-UI thread, then you must Invoke to update the UI objects.

FrameReceived is subscribed to an event in my main form. The code I show here is in another form.

Well, I'm not able to reproduce that. A possible reason is what I've mentioned earlier. Show us the raising event context in your main Form.

you seem to be right! I called FrameReceived from the form it belongs and it did work! But my event already has invoke....now I don't know what I should put inside my event handler
private void OnFrameRecebido(FrameCan frame) {     FrameRecebido?.Invoke(frame); }

I can't post an answer based on a guess even if it was right. Now, replace the code in FrameReceived handler with if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action(() => FrameReceived(somePgn))); else { ... }. Move your current code to the else block. See how it goes. Also, and based on your question, make sure that you set dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;.

It works when I set dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false; as you said. The other alteration was not necessary. Thank you very much!!!
